# Blender eevee lighting problem

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

New blender user! Just got into Daz3D again after years and I wanted to see how blender works with it. Blender is so organized with the materials! But I ran into a problem when I was lighting the model with Textures. I cant zoom in too close or else the camera casts a shadow on the model? Idk but it darkens the whole model. Only when I zoom out it fixes the lighting issue.[[image: ][1]]
[image]

Comment: Strange, but AFAIK the camera does not cast any shadow of any kind in blender. Something else must be going on - I'm guessing related to normals.

Comment: Are you using an alpha build?

Comment: Yes im using 2.81a

Comment: Have you set the *Color Space* of the *Image Texture* node that uses the normal image to *Non Color*?